# Returning LiveData of an Interface from Room?

Tags: android, persistence, android-room, android-livedata, android-jetpack

**TL;DR version**

I'd like to have a method whose returning signature is `LiveData<User>`, in which `User` is an interface. And the implementation returns a `LiveData<UserEntity>` in which `UserEntity` is a concrete class that extends `User`. Like following:

```
fun getUser(id: String): LiveData<User> {
    // for brevity
    return LiveData<UserEntity>() // actual code will retrieve data from db
}
```

The compiler complains `return type not match error`

**TL; version**

I'm reading the [Jetpack guide](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide). In it, they designed a `DataRepository` class which can retrive data from either DB or WebService, as shown in this graph:
[image: app structure from Jetpack guide]
And they claim that

> Notice that each component depends only on the component one level below it.

It's an appealing design, I actually tried to replicate it in my own project. **However**, I found `WebService` inevitably depends on `Room`, because it's method `getUser()` returns a `LiveData` of `User`, which is a **Room Entity**.

This issue might not break the app, but it's contradicting the fundamental design of the"separation of concerns" principle, and is aesthetically ugly IMHO.

My question is: are there any workaround? I've tried to refactor `User` as an interface and implemented an `UserEntity` class that extends it. Shown below:

```
interface User {
    val id: String
    val name: String
    val lastName: String
}
```

```
@Entity(tableName="users")
data class UserEntity(
    override val id: String
    override val name: String
    override val lastName: String) : User
```

```
@Dao
interface UserDao() {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM users where id = :id")
    fun getUser(id: String): LiveData<UserEntity> // UserEntity instead of User, because Room doesn't know how to construct an interface
}
```

Note I have to return `UserEntity` intead of `User`, because Room doesn't know how to construct an interface.

**Here is the problem:** the following code won't compile:

```
interface DataRepository {
    fun getUser(id: String): LiveData<User>
}
class DbRepository : DataRepository {
    // ... init db connection/userDao ...
    override fun getUser(id: String): LiveData<User> = userDao.getUser(id)
}
```

The error indicates 
`data type mismatch: LiveData<User> vs. LiveData<UserEntity>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above code won't work, as you can't expect a function to return multiple data types. I recommend using one User class which merges both Room and GSON mapping.

```
@Entity(tableName="users")
data class Users(
  @PrimaryKey           // Room annotation
  @SerializedName("id") // Gson annotation
  val id: String,
  @ColumnInfo(name = "name") 
  @SerializedName("name")   
  val name: String,
  @ColumnInfo(name = "lastName") 
  @SerializedName("lastName")    
  val lastName: String,
)
```

You can get rid of your UserEntity class and use the above as the DTO for both API and DB repository.

Comment: But that still won't eliminate the WebService's dependency of Room isn't it. In this way I can't unit test WebService without Room. (And many other shortcomings of inter-dependencies)

Comment: @victl I personally don't think this will affect your unit tests. This is just a data class and your unit tests will be against your web services repository and your local store repository.

Comment: @victl This is google's sample which follows the same approach as I suggested. https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/vo/User.kt